# Guardar arquivos temporariamento no sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, arquivo, front-end

Olá, gostaria de saber saber se é possível armazenar arquivos no sessionStorage e como eu posso fazer isso. Tentei com os métodos JSON.stringfy() e JSON.parse() e não obitive sucesso da seguinte forma

```js
var elemento = document.getElementById('inputComArquivo');

sessionStorage.setItem('arquivos', JSON.stringfy(elemento.files));
```

Comment: Acho que a API de `storage` tem um limite de memória, e armazenar arquivos grandes não é uma boa ideia. Os arquivos serão grandes?

Comment: Pesquisando por aí, aparentemente o limite é 5MB. E tem [esse site](http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/) pra testar na prática :) . E não consigo imaginar um caso que faça sentido isso, você realmente precisa guardar o conteúdo de um arquivo ali? Talvez seu problema seja outro e você está tentando resolver de um jeito ruim

Comment: Olá, obrigado pelo retorno, valeu mesmo! Bom, no caso é uma página de cadastro com um campo em que posso anexar até 3 arquivos (.pdf, xlsx, etc...). 
Se eu por exemplo clico em "cadastrar" e houver algum erro no cadastro como um campo vazio, a página simplesmente recarrega me alertando quais campos eu nao preenchi e é assim que eu perco os arquivos que eu anexei previamente e tenho que anexar de novo no cadastro (típico do Django)
A minha terefa é justamente  manter os arquivos que eu inseri caso a página recarregue por conta de erro no cadastro. É só pra isso.